# docker-compose.yml file errors on running docker-compose up

Tags: macos, docker, redis, yaml, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version:'2':  
services: 
    redis:
        image: redis  
        environment: 
            - HOST='localhost'
            - PORT=6379
        ports: 
            -"0.0.0.0:${PORT}:6379"
```

I get this error on running docker-compose up:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid service name 'services' - only [a-zA-Z0-9\._\-] characters are allowed
Unsupported config option for services: 'redis'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just remove last character ":" into string `version:'2':`

after it `docker-compose.yml` must be like

```
version:'2'
services: 
redis:
    image: redis  
    environment: 
        - HOST='localhost'
        - PORT=6379
    ports: 
        -"0.0.0.0:${PORT}:6379"
```

Comment: What you present is an invalid YAML file, and will not parse with the YAML parser that docker-compose uses. It is also not a valid `docker-compose.yml` file for various reasons even if the first line would be corrected. Very friendly of the OP to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your file. The one causing the syntax error is that you have an extra colon on the first line:

```
version:'2':
```

that way you define a scalar string key `version:'2'` with value of `null`. Since you are therefore not defining the `version` of the docker compose file, the rest of the file (which is version 2 oriented) fails. This is best resolved by adding a space after `version:`

In addition your `ports` definition is incorrect, the value for that should be a `sequence`/`list`, and you again specify a scalar string `-"0.0.0.0:${PORT}:6379"` because there is no space after the initial dash.

Change your `docker_compose.yaml` file to:

```
version: '2'  
          # ^ no colon here
      # ^ space here
services: 
    redis:
        image: redis  
        environment: 
            - HOST='localhost'
            - PORT=6379
        ports: 
            - "0.0.0.0:${PORT}:6379"
           # ^ extra space here
```